# MySQL INNER JOIN E:#1054 - I don't get it

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.item, t2.tag
FROM items AS t1
INNER JOIN tagged AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.item_id
```

returns #1054 - Unknown column 't1.id' in 'field list'

I don't get why it does fail. I copied that syntax straight from manual.

Comment: Did you create the table first? Did you name the columns correctly?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE items`

Answer (score 5):

`t1` and `t2` are aliases, standing for the `items` table and the `tagged` table respectively (`items AS t1`, `tagged AS t2`). By saying `t1.id`, you're saying `use the field (column) named id in the items table`

If a column named `id` doesn't exist in your `items` table, then the query will fail. Check your table structure by typing `DESCRIBE items`, this will display all the columns in the table.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please remove it and post it as a comment.

Comment: oh look it's the answer police!

Comment: I don't understand why you feel the need to get involved in this, Hituptony. @njk Why wouldn't this be an answer? I'm new to SO, so that's a genuine question. It seems like the cause of his problem to me.

Comment: @Kai Welcome to StackOverflow. [Here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) is an excellent guide on how to form your answer.

Comment: This guys is a predicitive badass. I had items.id in previous version, now it is items_id but a nice guy who did it didn't wrote that in log.

Comment: @user2044390 What does "predicitive" mean?

Comment: @Kai I've changed my mind. Your answer is acceptable.

Comment: @njk haha, alright. Thanks for the guide though, I can see what you meant.

Comment: @Kai I just didn't feel like there was an acceptable answer since it was evidently an error on OP's behalf.